# mysqld: can not open shared library 'C:\laragon\bin\mysql\m...\component_reference_model.dll

Tags: mysql, laragon

I'm working on MySQL with Laragon and I get MySQL failed error suddenly
this is the error log i have get from mysqld.log
2023-09-20T13:59:40.351257Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
2023-09-20T13:59:40.351310Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.30-winx64\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.30) starting as process 4224
2023-09-20T13:59:40.396159Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-20T13:59:40.638227Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013882] [InnoDB] Missing redo log file .#innodb_redo#ib_redo6 (with start_lsn = 19656704).
2023-09-20T13:59:40.639105Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2023-09-20T13:59:40.724721Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2023-09-20T13:59:40.729858Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-09-20T13:59:40.730488Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

[error I get from Laragon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmYoX.png)

and my phpmyadmin says  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it . I have tried by reinstalling MySQL and laragon .do you have any other solutions?